# Вопрос по хранимой процедуре

Tags: sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUsers
@Email NVARCHAR(30) ,
@Password NVARCHAR(20),
@Nickname NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF EXISTS(SELECT UsersTable.Email FROM UsersTable WHERE UsersTable.Email = @Email) --check email
   BEGIN
          SELECT -1 AS UserId -- Username exists.
   END

   ELSE
   BEGIN
          INSERT INTO UsersTable(Email, Pass, Login, Data_reg)
          VALUES
          (@Email, @Password, @Nickname, GETDATE())
          select 1  
   END                 
END
```

ХП сверху, вопрос такой что это значит строка SELECT -1 AS UserId

Comment: А это какой SQL ? Если MySQL - то такая процедура вернет набор данных из одной колонки с именем UserId и строкой с значением -1

Comment: Это НЕ MySQL - там это гарантированный syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что это значит строка SELECT -1 AS UserId

Эта строка означает "выбрать значение -1 в поле с именем UserId". Т.е. вернуть набор записей, где количество записей равно 1, количество полей в записи равно 1, имя этого поля UserId, а значение в этом поле в единственной записи равно -1.

Answer (score 0):

ЕСЛИ пользователь существует

- вернуть -1

ИНАЧЕ

- добавить нового пользователя
- вернуть 1